# How to register a user via modal after clicking a link in the shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, user-registration

I have a fair understanding of PHP, but am rather new to WordPress.

On a previous HTML/PHP/JS-only website, I have a PHP script that queries a MySQL DB table and lists the entries (*seminars with date and location*).

For each listed seminar, there is a link to a registration form (window popup). This is all working perfectly.

Now I want to do the same in a WP-based website by embedding the seminar listing within a WP page.
I have successfully embedded a shortcode into said WP page. This shortcode calls a function that does exactly the same as the PHP script mentioned above.

That part is working fine. I get the listing with the seminars and their corresponding registration form links.

But now I'm stuck at next step: how to have the registration form popup when clicking on the link generated via the shortcode?

Maybe the shortcode route is not the appropriate one for this kind of endeavour?

I would appreciate any hint/suggestion/pointer.

Thanks in advance.
Larry.

Excerpt of PHP called by the shortcode:

```
   function golwebdes_seminar_output () {

include('golwebdes_conf.inc.php');

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8');

global $wpdb;

$seminare = $seminare_gki;

if (isset($_GET['semid'])) { // Einzelseminar
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$seminare." WHERE id=".$_GET['semid'];
    $result = $wpdb->get_row($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $html = '<div class="container-fluid">';

    $kateg = $result->kategorie;
    $html .= '<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="row" style="margin-bottom:3%;">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <img src="/pics/icon-workshops-indien.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-left:3%;">';
    $html .= '<p><span class="small">'.$seminarkategorien[$kateg].'</span><br><span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$result->titel.'</span></p>';
    $html .= '<p>'.$result->kurzinfo.'</p>';
    $html .= '<p>'.$result->beschreibung.'</p>';
    $html .= '<p>'.$result->inhalt.'</p>';


    /**** BEGINN - Erzeugen der Termine: Ort Datum Anmeldelink ***/
    $termine='';

    /* 1 */
    if ($result->ort1!='')
        $ort1 = $result->ort1;

    if ($result->datum_beginn1!=0) {
        if ($result->datum_ende1!=0) {
            if (date("m",$result->datum_beginn1) == date("m",$result->datum_ende1))
                $datum1 = date("j.",$result->datum_beginn1)."/".date("j.",$result->datum_ende1).strftime(" %B %Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $result->datum_beginn1)));
            }
        else 
            $datum1 = date("j.",$result->datum_beginn1).strftime(" %B %Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $result->datum_beginn1)));
        }
    else
        $datum1 = "Termin folgt.";

    if ($result->datum_ende1 !=0 && $result->datum_ende1 >= time())
        $termin1 = "<strong>".$ort1."</strong> ".$datum1." <a href=\"#\" class=\"anmeldung\" onclick=\"window.open('seminaranmeldung.php?s=".$result->id."&o=1','anmeldung','').focus();return false;\" >zur Anmeldung</a>";
    else if ($result->datum_ende1 ==0 && $result->datum_beginn1 !=0 && $result->datum_beginn1 >= time())
        $termin1 = "<strong>".$ort1."</strong> ".$datum1." <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('seminaranmeldung.php?s=".$result->id."&o=1','anmeldung','').focus();return false;\" class=\"anmeldung\">zur Anmeldung</a>";
    else if ($result->datum_beginn1 ==0)
        $termin1 = $ort1." ".$datum1;

    $termine = $termine.$termin1.'<br>';


    /* 2 */
    if ($result->ort2!='')
        $ort2 = $result->ort2;

    if ($result->datum_beginn2!=0) {
        if ($result->datum_ende2!=0) {
            if (date("m",$result->datum_beginn2) == date("m",$result->datum_ende2))
                $datum2 = date("j.",$result->datum_beginn2)."/".date("j.",$result->datum_ende2).strftime(" %B %Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $result->datum_beginn2)));
            }
        else 
            $datum2 = date("j.",$result->datum_beginn2).strftime(" %B %Y", strtotime(date("m/d/Y", $result->datum_beginn2)));
        }
    else
        $datum2 = "Termin folgt.";

    if ($result->datum_ende2 !=0 && $result->datum_ende2 >= time())
        $termin2 = "<strong>".$ort2."</strong> ".$datum2." <a href=\"#\" class=\"anmeldung\" onclick=\"window.open('seminaranmeldung.php?s=".$result->id."&o=2','anmeldung','').focus();return false;\"  >zur Anmeldung</a>";
    else if ($result->datum_ende2 ==0 && $result->datum_beginn2 !=0 && $result->datum_beginn2 >= time())
        $termin2 = "<strong>".$ort2."</strong> ".$datum2." <a href=\"#\" class=\"anmeldung\" onclick=\"window.open('seminaranmeldung.php?s=".$result->id."&o=2','anmeldung','').focus();return false;\"  >zur Anmeldung</a>";
    else if ($result->datum_beginn2 ==0)
        $termin2 = $ort2." ".$datum2;


    $termine = $termine.$termin2.'<br>';
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to WPSE. How does your modal actually handle the registration? How does it output data? Some code would be nice to be seen.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well, that's the point of my question. I don't have any working modal handling the registration. That's precisely what I'm trying to achieve... I'll try to post excerpts of the present code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved in two steps. First, create a registration form, then send the response to server and create the user.

Since you have skill in JS and HTML, I'll directly get to business. Below is a very simple registration form. You will set this form to be hidden, for now.

### Registration Form

```
<div id="ajax-register-modal">
    <input type="text" id="ajax-username" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Username', 'text-domain' ); ?>"/>
    <input type="password" id="ajax-password" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Password', 'text-domain' ); ?>"/>
    <span id="register-modal-send"><?php _e( 'Register', 'text-domain' ); ?></span>
</div>
```

Then when you click the link, you will make it visible by jQuery.

```
jQuery('#YourLinkID').click(function($){
    $('#ajax-register-modal').toggle();
});
```

So it pops up when we click the link. Now we send the data when the user clicks the register button.

Let's bind an action to our button:

```
jQuery('#register-modal-send').click(function($){
    registerTheUser();
});
```

### Server-side Registration

Now the AJAX handler:

```
function registerTheUser(){
    // Get the field values for username and password
    var username = $('#ajax-username').val();
    var password = $('#ajax-password').val();
    // Send them to server via AJAX
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'REST URL HERE',
        data: { ajaxUsername: username , ajaxPassword: password},
    });
}
```

But wait, where would the data go? The final stage is to create a REST handler in the back-end, to deal with the registration. We simply create a REST route and register the user.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to REST route for registration
    register_rest_route( 'LarryG001/v2', '/ajax_registration/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', // I suggest using POST
            'callback' => 'register_the_user' // Callback PHP function
    ) );
});
```

Alright, let the registration begin!

```
function register_the_user(){
    // Get the username and password
    $username = $_GET['ajaxUsername'];
    $password = $_GET['ajaxPassword'];
    // A basic creation of user based on username and password. Email is optional
    $id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
    // Return the ID of the new user
    return $id;
}
```

Remember the URL in our AJAX call? This is what we should use there, since our request goes to this URL:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/LarryG001/v2/ajax_registration/
```

Done. We just created a new user by using [`wp_create_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) function.

I omitted a lot of stuff here, such as checking if the values are set ( By using `if(isset($_GET['ajaxUsername'])` ).

After the data is returned, you can use it as your AJAX response.

Comment: Thank you. Wow, it's a lot to process for me now. I think I can make good use of the first parts. However, I will not need the "user registration" part, as I won't do that. But rather I will just send an email with the user data to the registration office... Unfortunately, I will not be able to work on all that right away...

Comment: But if I understand correctly, the "hidden registration form" must also be output by the function called through the shortcode?

Comment: @LarryG001 You're welcome. That's quite alright. I did a full process for you, so you can change wherever of it you want. Was just a demonstration  of how to connect a modal to back-end.

Comment: You can include the form in your shortcode, or anywhere on screen. Take a look at [this](http://photogram.wallpaperinho.com) page. Click on the login button to see the modal. You can check the source there.

Comment: I voted your answer as useful, but due to my low reputation, apparently it does not appear... Well...

Comment: @LarryG001 That's alright. I started with 1 rep too :)